# What causes the Webkit framework error in an Ionic/Cordova project?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I’m having some issues trying to get an old Cordova project running on my new Mac M1.

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.20.1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.5
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.801.3
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
   @angular/cli                  : 8.1.3
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.1.1

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 11.0.0
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0, ios 6.2.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 5.0.0, (and 11 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.15.4
   native-run  : 1.7.1

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/Users/me/Library/Android/sdk)
   ios-deploy        : 1.12.1
   ios-sim           : 8.0.2
   NodeJS            : v14.17.0 (/Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.0/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.14.13
   OS                : macOS Monterey
   Xcode             : Xcode 14.2 Build version 14C18
```

When I try and compile the project, I am running into some Pods issues, much like I have with the M1 across all of my projects, even my capacitor projects. However, now I am seeing this in my console when trying to run the project on an emulator from Xcode:

```
2023-02-27 14:44:05.262840-0600 MyApp[25026:6489696] [assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=2 "Specified target process does not exist" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Specified target process does not exist}>
2023-02-27 14:44:05.262911-0600 MyApp[25026:6489696] [ProcessSuspension] 0x1520226a0 - ProcessAssertion::acquireSync Failed to acquire RBS assertion 'WebProcess Background Assertion' for process with PID=25049, error: Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=2 "Specified target process does not exist" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Specified target process does not exist}
2023-02-27 14:44:05.267957-0600 MyApp[25026:6489397] [ProcessSuspension] ProcessAssertion::remainingRunTimeInSeconds failed to get handle for process with PID=25049
2023-02-27 14:44:35.251443-0600 MyApp[25026:6489397] Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.WebContent: 113: Could not find specified service
```

Any thoughts what may be causing these issues? My emulator is iPhone 14 running iOS 16.2.

1. I've updated the project `cordova-ios` to 6.2.0
2. Everything appears to be good in the Xcode project settings
3. I've restarting the emulator
4. I've tried delete and reinstalling the app on the emulator
5. I've tried running the app on a different emulator

Comment: For one thing you have a mis-match between your CLI and your framework.  Ionic CLI                     : 6.20.1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.5

Comment: And https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/upgrading-to-ionic-6 Ionic 6 supports Angular 12+. ...yours shows Angular 8